# Which data structure(s) do relational database systems use to store data?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, data-structures

Would you also describe the benefits of using the specific structures in the context of a database system? I was asked this in an interview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B-trees. Hierarchical index, sorted keys and balanced tree enabling fast retrieval are the main benefits and coping well with large amounts of data and inserts/updates/deletes.